# Showing react UI in laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am doing a CMS project with laravel & ReactJS as microservice. In backend, for adding/editing content of a page like we do in any cms, I need to show that page in edit page screen as UI from frontend. A common solution is to make the page again in laravel. But in this way I have to make all the pages twice ( both in laravel & Reactjs ). Is there any way to do so without creating pages in laravel?

Comment: Make a SPA with react an only make the API endpoints in Laravel.

Comment: Yes @Christophvh. I did so. I am passing the page contents to spa made on reactJS through api. But in dashboard made in laravel, i have to show the page UI while editing contents. My problem is at this point..how to show the page that is made in spa in react in dashboard edit page screen?

Comment: you don't pass the page 'contents' you pass json-objects to your React SPA and only react is responsible for the UI.  The api-resources form laravel should help you a lot https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Comment: You are right @Christophvh. I am passing json objects to SPA. I think you can't pick my point. Let's think admin wants to edit a page content from backend like dashboard. So when admin go to edit a page, the page should appear as same as it is in SPA. I have designed the page in SPA not in laravel. So how will I show a page in laravel that is designed in SPA?

Comment: I have tried web scraping or iframe. Is there any other way to do so?